# Calculate the fourth proportional of the given numbers (Grade 7)

Tags: education

My son has this:

Calculate the fourth proportional of the given numbers: 1/9, 1/6, 1/3

Similarly, another question:

Calculate the fourth proportional of the given numbers: 9.1; 6.5; 2.8

It should be something really simple because he is only in 7th grade, but for some reason I myself don't get it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Finding the $4$th proportional is an exercise in executing "product of means"="product of extremes"

For example on problem 1, you would solve
$$1/9:1/6::1/3:x$$

Since the product of the means is the product of the extremes, you would get
$$
1/6 \times 1/3 = 1/9 \times x$$

Solving for $x$ gives $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

The second example is similar. The correct answer should be $2$. (Obtained by setting $9.1x=(6.5)(2.8)$ )

Comment: Thank you!!! After reading your reply, I realized that I completely misunderstood what's required. Now I get it :)